# Trouble importing an image from a postgresql table to Geoserver

Tags: javascript, postgresql, jsp, postgis, geoserver

Last weeks I am creating an application. I want to import from postgresql a database to Geoserver so that I will call WFS-T service after to my project using js language.
For first time I have to use also an image column to my table and here is the PROBLEM. Until now I used many types like oid, bytea, raster but those types worked only for import and export in postgresql. When I tried to open a record I put in Geoserver I did not see neither the image nor the link but only a number. I found that Geoserver is not able to share binary image data stored in a postgis layer column by default. Could you please inform me about potential solutions because I am stuck...
I tried to use some solution of the past questions in stackoverflow but still have problem.
Thanks in advance,
Nikos!

Comment: 1)insert into mytable(bdata) select bytea_import('D:/123.jpg');

Comment: An example of my table is:
CREATE TABLE cevents
("Name" character(20),
 "Location" text,
 "Remark/Comment" text, 
pic oid,
lng double precision,
lat double precision, 
id real, geom_shape geometry(Point,4326), 
"Sector" sectors)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE); 
ALTER TABLE cevents OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: 2)INSERT INTO events VALUES ('Amazing',lo_import('D:/amfi10.jpg'), 2.60, 40.31, 1 ); SELECT lo_export(cevents.pic, 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\night.jpg') FROM cevents WHERE id= 1; Those examples worked in postgresql but no in Geoserver.